# Django progress bar while saving the object model

Tags: django

The problem is: There is one model with FileField, which poured files in csv. When you save the object model has parsed csv 1 and 2 to create model objects. This was all done. Now the question is - how to make the visualization of the process of creating a model object 2, while maintaining the object modeli1? So I'm in the admin panel insert in the file csv, click "save" and I want to display the process of creating objects modeli2.

Sorry my bad english

Comment: This is a very vague question, so my vague answer: think about using javascript to display the progress.

Answer (score 0):

ok. Example:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
  field = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
# ...many different fields

class Model1(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()  /upload csv

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        csv_file = self.file.path
        dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_file), delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
        for row in dataReader:
           obj, created = Model2.objects.get_or_create(field=self, 
#                                                 other fields
                                             )
```

I want, when i save object of Model 1 at admin page to see progress of creating objects of Model 2